# Getting id from url using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567%2Fsubtitle
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F123456
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F123456%2Fsubtitle
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567%2F
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F123456%2F
```

The URL's always start with:

```
http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F
```

The ids are always numeric, however the number of digits can vary.

How to get the id (`1234567` and `123456`) from above sample URL's?

I've tried using the following pattern without luck (it doesn't return any matches):

```
/^http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F(\d)$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper URL parsing functions you can do this:

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
if (isset($params['url'])) {
    parse_str(parse_url($params['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
    if (isset($params['movie'])) {
        $movie = $params['movie'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to first [parse this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) and extract the `url` query string parameter and url decoding it:

```
function getParameterByName(url, name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

like this:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567';
var p = getParameterByName(url, 'url');
```

and then use some regex to parse `p` and extract the necessary information like `/\d+/`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way without parsing too. Assuming $url = URL

http://codepad.org/t91DK9H2

```
$url = "http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567%2Fsubtitle";
$reg = "/^([\w\d\.:]+).*movie%2F(\d+).*/";
$id = preg_replace($reg,"$2",$url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = array(
   'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567'
   , 'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567%2Fsubtitle'
   , 'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F123456'
   , 'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F123456%2Fsubtitle'
   , 'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F1234567%2F'
   , 'http://example.com/movie.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F123456%2F'
);

foreach ($urls as $url) {
   if (preg_match('/%2Fmovie%2F(\d+)/', $url, $matches)) {
      var_dump($matches[1]);
   }
}
```

KISS.  I was originally going to use `parse_url()`, but there is no way to parse a query string without regular expressions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes you need to escape some special characters.
try:

/^http://example.com/movie.swf\?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmovie%2F(\d+)$/